# Route request to specific instance

Tags: google-app-engine

Does anybody know if GAE provides a way to route a request to a specified instance? The startup of new instances is killing me on facebook URL linter requests since they timeout before a new instance can start up sometimes. I have no way to control this timeout either. So what I'd like to do is to keep specified instances idle for these calls without needing to hack around it with cron jobs. I think this would be more cost effective as well.

Comment: Are you running a paid app?  Have you already tried setting the number of idle instances and/or reducing the maximum pending latency?  If not, those two settings are available with paid apps.

You can specify an instance if you use a backend, but I don't think you'd want to do that - it won't scale like the normal frontend instances do.

Comment: Yes I am and yes changing the idle instances does help. But the issue will always exist if GAE has to create a new instance for all my requests. I'm ok with all of my requests firing up new instances with the exception of the linter requests. So it would be easier to optimize against the linter alone.

Comment: The linter as in the URL debugger?  You can point that at a backend instance if it's just for debugging, though you have to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

The new modules allows for direct addressing of instances. Much like how backends used to work.

Like so:

```
http://instance.version.module.app-id.appspot.com
```

[Read more in the documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a dedicated set of "always alive" instances to handle just those calls. Backends might be a good solution for that. You can set a separate url address to route to a specific backend.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html#Addressing_Backends

Comment: Note that having your requests directed to Backends defeats the purpose of auto-scalability in GAE, and brought you back to the traditional "rent-a-server" model compared to "infinite-scalability-as-you-need" model provided by the Frontend instances.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for frontends, but you can have requests directed to specific backends, and you can make backends externally accessible if you choose.

I'd suggest working on your app to improve loading time, though. If it's taking so long a bot gives up, that's got to have serious implications for usability by your users. Also, make sure you've got warmup requests enabled.